# Wordpress bootstrap navbar dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

My question is simply put, how do I add the ability to dynamically add sub menu items from child pages, in the form of a dropdown, in a Wordpress site using bootstrap navbar. I have it setup to add menu items as a regular page is added using the following code:

```
    <nav class="navbar nav-main navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/brtheme/images/blue-realty-logo.png"></img></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right nav-main">
                <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
                <!--<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>-->
              <?php 
                wp_nav_menu(array( 
                  'theme_location' => 'primary',
                  'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                  'container'      => false,
                  'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
                  'depth'          => '2'    
                ));
              ?>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Every time a page is added through the Wordpress dashboard it gets added to my navbar but how do I implement the use of child pages?

Comment: add a dropdown plugin is the fastest..

Comment: Ok....that's great but I don't want to use a plugin any time there's hard coding. Nonetheless, I'm not sure if it's good practice but I found a way by creating a menu for each dropdown to act as a kind of submenu